# Using LIKE, ?, for two columns in SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

So, I added a second parameter to my SQLite query.  It was working fine when just searching and identifying by DATE alone, but I wanted to add the additional identifier TIME to keep from deleting rows not intended.  Here is wht I tried, but it is wrong although should give you an idea of what I'm attempting to do.

```
public void deleteRowByDateTime (String d, String t){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String[] deleteDate = new String[] { "%" +d +"%" };
    String[] deleteTime = new String[] { "%" +t +"%" };
    db.execSQL("DELETE FROM walk_run_table WHERE DATE LIKE ? AND TIME LIKE ?", deleteDate, deleteTime);
    db.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that you must use an array is that it is possible to put multiple value in it. So do that, instead of trying to use two arrays:

```java
String[] args = new String[] { "%" + d +"%", "%" + t +"%" };
db.execSQL("DELETE ... ? ... ?", args);
```

Comment: TIME and DATE are different columns.  Will this still work for me?

Comment: Each `?` uses one of the entries from the array. (This is not directly related with columns.)